# bootstrap form helper phone wont work in ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

My Bootstrap phone form helper is working fine but when I try to add more textboxes using jQuery/javascript it does not work.

Working with normal form:

```
<div class="n_g_p_pop" id="mainprice">
    <label> 
        <span id="base_rental">Base rental rate</span> 
        <i class="gn_icon8" title="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="$" id="base_rental_rate" class="bfh-phone" data-format="$dddd"/>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

on add more button click (Bootstrap phone form not working)

```
var id = 101;
function add_extra()  {
    var data = '<div id="new_element_' + id + '" class="month_int_b"><div class="gn_b_1"> <i class="gn_icon12"></i><div class="gn_b_1_i"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="$" class="bfh-phone" data-format="$dddd" /></div></div><div class="gn_b_1"> <i class="gn_icon12"></i><div class="gn_b_1_i"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="$" class="bfh-phone" data-format="$dddd"/></div></div><div class="gn_ad_m1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="remove_extra(' + id + ')"></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
    id++;
    $('#add_new_element').append(data);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please ignore ajax code and check " add_extra() " function code. thanks

Comment: When i try to add html code ("<input type="text" value="" placeholder="$" class="bfh-phone" data-format="$dddd"/>") using java script, it does not work.

Comment: make sure if this element `$('#add_new_element')` exists

Comment: yes ... its exists.. all things working properly instead of bootstrap form helper functionality.

Comment: By form helper you mean jquery plugin? can you show us the code where the plugin is initialized? I'm guessing you need to manually call the plugin on the newly created element

Comment: please open (http://beta.guestnest.com/news/page_3) click on monthly icon , pop-up will appear. 

select "No" in " Is this an "all-inclusive" rental " 

"Monthly bills worksheet"  in frist 4 box its working but when you try to add more and enter any value. it will not work

Comment: i found solutions  

need to add this code after data append 

$('form input[type="text"].bfh-phone, form input[type="tel"].bfh-phone, span.bfh-phone').each(function () { var $phone; $phone = $(this); $phone.bfhphone($phone.data()); });

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the bfh control manually after you've added it to the DOM.
It's a bit messy and they could really have given us an init() function or something. Anyway, this should work:

```
$('form input[type="text"].bfh-phone, form input[type="tel"].bfh-phone, span.bfh-phone').each(function() {
   var $phone = $(this);
   $phone.bfhphone($phone.data());
});
```